# Выборка из таблицы по 2м и больше значениям одного столбца mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Есть такая таблица
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно выбрать page_id у которых filter_id = 1 и 6
При таком запросе

```
SELECT page_id FROM oc_diagnostic_page_filter WHERE filter_id IN(1,6);
```

в рузультат попадает и page_id 1 и 7
при таком

```
SELECT page_id FROM oc_diagnostic_page_filter WHERE filter_id = 1 AND filter_id = 6;
```

вообще ничего не выдает

Comment: ```filter_id = 1 AND filter_id = 6;``` что вы хотите этим сказать и каким образом пытаясь фильтровать filter_id вы собираетесь получать page_id - из текста вопроса непонятны. Структура таблицы, тестовые данные, текст запроса - должны находится в виде ТЕКСТА непосредственно в вопросе.

Comment: Обычное реляционное деление. Отбор, группировка, подсчёт уникальных значений, отбор, где их количество равно количеству значений при отборе.

Comment: А что не так с первым запросом? Вы хотите получить page_id, у которых filter_id = 1 или filter_id = 6. Их Вы и получаете.